# Java: TreeSet compareTo method triggered at first add call

Tags: java, exception, comparison, treeset

The following java code utilizes a `TreeSet` to collect objects derived from the class `MyClass` which doesn't implement the `Comparable` interface nor have a `compareTo()` method to perform the comparison between objects. By not providing that comparison method, we expect the raising of an exception during the addition of the **second** object, not the **first** one as soon as comparison is ambiguous with only one object.

JDK: 1.7

Question:
Why the `compareTo()` is triggered on the **first** add `tree.add(m1)` ?

Code:

```
package javaapplication1;

import java.util.*;

class MyClass
{
    int _x;
    MyClass(int x)
    {
        _x = x;
    }
}

public class JavaApplication1 
{
     public static void main(String[] args) 
     {
         MyClass m1 = new MyClass(5);
         MyClass m2 = new MyClass(3);

         TreeSet tree = new TreeSet();
         tree.add(m1);
         tree.add(m2);
     }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`TreeSet` is implemented on top of `TreeMap`. So `TreeSet.add()` calls to `TreeMap.put(Object, Object)` method. Please see the below:

```
public V put(K key, V value) {
        Entry<K,V> t = root;
        if (t == null) {
            compare(key, key); //this is the culprit

            root = new Entry<>(key, value, null);
            size = 1;
            modCount++;
            return null;
        }
    ……………
    ……………
    ……………
}
```

Now as the `root` is `null` so the flow will go inside the `if (t == null) {` hence calls `compare(key, key)`.

```
final int compare(Object k1, Object k2) {
    return comparator==null ? ((Comparable<? super K>)k1).compareTo((K)k2)
        : comparator.compare((K)k1, (K)k2);
}
```

As inside the `compare` method it is typecasting `k1, k2` `Comparable` and your class does not implement `Comparable` hence the exception:

> `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException:` .

This code is as per JDK 1.7.

Comment: @downvoter don't behave like looser, dare to comment.

Comment: can you specify which jdk version?

Answer (score 2):

This is the actual code from `TreeMap`'s `put` method. You will get a `ClassCastException` the **first time** you try to `add` because your `key` is not `Comparable`. Please note that `TreeSet` uses a `TreeMap` internally and anything you put in a `TreeSet` will be a `key` (`value` is not used).

```
    Comparator<? super K> cpr = comparator;
        if (cpr != null) {
            do {
                parent = t;
                cmp = cpr.compare(key, t.key);
                if (cmp < 0)
                    t = t.left;
                else if (cmp > 0)
                    t = t.right;
                else
                    return t.setValue(value);
            } while (t != null);
        }
        else {
            if (key == null)
                throw new NullPointerException();
            Comparable<? super K> k = (Comparable<? super K>) key;
            // ^^ -- ClassCastException here
            do {
                parent = t;
                cmp = k.compareTo(t.key);
                if (cmp < 0)
                    t = t.left;
                else if (cmp > 0)
                    t = t.right;
                else
                    return t.setValue(value);
            } while (t != null);
        }
```

Comment: can you specify which jdk version? I have 1.6.0_33 and it looks almost like @Trying 's version (with a comment that starts with "TBD...")